# Dynamic physics body eventually gets pushed off screen

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, physics

I have two SKNodes. I added my character as a child of the first one, and the map as the child of the second one. I have some physics bodies along the walls of the map that the character contacts. I have a virtual joystick on the screen that moves the second SKNode around. (To give the appearance of movement.)

The way I move my second (map) SKNode has created this weird dilemma. I can't figure it out.

Because he is dynamic, my character gets pushed aside and doesn't stay centered when he collides with the physics bodies along the walls of the map. I *need* him to stay centered when he collides with the walls of the map, even if he slams directly head-on into the physics bodies. (FYI, the game is a 2D top-down RPG game. Similar to Chrono Trigger, Final Fantasy, Dragon Quest, etc. Not like Castlevania or Terraria.)

**Virtual Joystick Code:**

```
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.location(in: self)
        if isTracking == true && location.x >= -(self.frame.width / 2) {

            v = CGVector(dx: location.x - DPad.position.x, dy: location.y - DPad.position.y)
            let angle = atan2(v.dy, v.dx)
            let deg = angle * CGFloat(180 / Double.pi)

            let Length:CGFloat = DPad.frame.size.height / 2
            let xDist: CGFloat = sin(angle - 1.57079633) * Length
            let yDist: CGFloat = cos(angle - 1.57079633) * Length


            xJoystickDelta = thumbNode.position.x - DPad.position.x
            yJoystickDelta = thumbNode.position.y - DPad.position.y
        }
    }
}
```

**Movement of the map code:**

```
override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    // Called before each frame is rendered
    let xScale = CGFloat(0.056) //adjust to your preference
    let yScale = CGFloat(0.056) //adjust to your preference

    let xAdd = xScale * self.xJoystickDelta
    let yAdd = yScale * self.yJoystickDelta

    map.position.x -= xAdd
    map.position.y -= yAdd
}
```

The physics are set up like normal. I used an enumeration to determine the category bit masks of each of the bodies. The character node is dynamic and the walls are not. None of the bodies are affected by gravity. The physics work great. In fact, they actually work too well. How do I keep my player centered? Is there a way to not make him dynamic but also have him contact the walls?

Comment: Why don't use SKCameraNode?

Comment: I agree with @SimonePistecchia, just place an SKCameraNode as a child of your main character, and your character will always be at the center of your screen

Comment: I didn't even know SKCameraNodes Existed. The more you know...‍♂️